# Stack to the Future

Tags: popularity-contest

Welcome Back to the Future's fans and enthusiastic codegolfers.

Let's begin with this simple statement : [Marty arrives in 2015 in one month (On october the 21st !)](http://istodaythedaymartymcflyarriveswhenhetravelstothefuture.com/). Therefore I propose we use the time remaining to pay him and the saga the best homage we can.

### Task

Marty left for 2015 on *October* the *26*, *1985*. Thus, you will have to write 3 code snippets of respective length 10, 26 and 85 in the language of your choice. Once executed, I'd like to see a visual representation of at least one of the 3 following symbols of Back to the Future :

**The Delorean**

[image]

**The Logo**

as seen here :

[image]

Or (since Marty arrives in 2015 in the 2nd movie), the Grays Sports Almanac :

[image]

I don't excpect a copy of those images which are just examples. I expect your creatives ways to display one of those symbols from the Back to the Future franchise.

### The rules

- This is a popularity contest that will stop at the [end of the countdown (i.e. october 21st)](http://istodaythedaymartymcflyarriveswhenhetravelstothefuture.com/). Highest upvoted answer by then wins.
- You have to stick to one language for the three snippets.
- The 3 snippets can act separately to produce 3 results or together and produce one bigger result.
- You can use any language you'd like, even [Piet](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) if you want.
- You can of course use a language that have already been used as long as the result clearly differs from the first answer.
- The visual representation can be anything you'd like, from ASCII art to producing a JPG file. It can even be an animation if you feel like it.

### Additional Information

- [Refrain from using the standards loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- Be creative ! We have seen that we can [tweet mathematical art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art), you can even [draw with your CPU](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33059/draw-with-your-cpu) so show me the best of your language.

The format of the answer can follow something along the line :

**Snipet length 10**

```
some_code;
...
```

**Snippet length 26**

```
some_more_code;
```

**Snippet length 85**

```
some_final_code;
...
```

**Output**

The output or a link to the output.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. This question comes under the standard complaint "this is an art contest, not a programming contest" (potentially it's a literature contest in this case.) An example of a narrower question (which would be on topic) would be a code-golf to draw the logo of the Delorean Motor Company (but you would have to specify exactly how it would be drawn.) Writing a good challenge is hard. Feel free to post your challenges in http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599 for feedback before you post.

Comment: @steveverrill I did exactly what you suggested last, I'm waiting for some more feedback on this challenge in order to narrow it properly. Thanks for your comment !